# How I can delete frametitle after pagebreak in mdframed box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can delete title after pagebreak in mdframed box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84946/how-i-can-delete-title-after-pagebreak-in-mdframed-box)

I try to make a box with the title "Summary" by `mdframed` package.

With the code I attach, the title "Summary" appears in the second page after pagebreak. 
But I think it seems not good looking. How I can delete the title "Summary " after pagebreak?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[framemethod=pgf]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzstyle{titlebox} = [draw=black,white,fill=white,text=black,right, minimum height=.5cm]

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd\mdfcreateextratikz{%
    \node[titlebox,xshift=\tmplen,anchor=center] at (P-|O) {\raisebox{3\depth}{\mdf@frametitlefont{ Summary }}};}

\newlength\tmplen

\mdfdefinestyle{myboxstyle}{%
    outerlinewidth=.4pt,
    innerlinewidth=0pt,
    roundcorner=0pt,
    linecolor=black,
    innertopmargin=1.5\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=.5\baselineskip,
    skipabove=4.5ex,
    skipbelow=3ex,
    needspace=3\baselineskip,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
    leftmargin=-.5em,
    rightmargin=-.5em,
    settings={\tmplen=\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin+\rightmargin-2\mdf@outerlinewidth@length\relax\tmplen=.5\tmplen},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{mdframed}[style=myboxstyle]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).