# How I can delete title after pagebreak in mdframed box?

Tags: mdframed

How I can delete frametitle after pagebreak in mdframed box?

I try to make a box with the title "Summary" by mdframed package.

With the code I attach, the title "Summary" appears in the second page after pagebreak. 
But I think it seems not good looking. How I can delete the title "Summary " after pagebreak?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[framemethod=pgf]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzstyle{titlebox} = [draw=black,white,fill=white,text=black,right, minimum height=.5cm]

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd\mdfcreateextratikz{%
    \node[titlebox,xshift=\tmplen,anchor=center] at (P-|O) {\raisebox{3\depth}{\mdf@frametitlefont{ Summary }}};}

\newlength\tmplen

\mdfdefinestyle{myboxstyle}{%
outerlinewidth=.4pt,
innerlinewidth=0pt,
roundcorner=0pt,
linecolor=black,
innertopmargin=1.5\baselineskip,
innerbottommargin=.5\baselineskip,
skipabove=4.5ex,
skipbelow=3ex,
needspace=3\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
leftmargin=-.5em,
rightmargin=-.5em,
settings={\tmplen=\dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin+\rightmargin-2\mdf@outerlinewidth@length\relax\tmplen=.5\tmplen},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{mdframed}[style=myboxstyle]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `\mdfcreateextratikz` is executed in every frame. If you want to add material to special frame segments use the commands `\mdf@Xextra` whereby `X` stands for:

- single
- first
- middle
- second

In your case:

```
\renewrobustcmd\mdf@singleextra{%
    \node[titlebox,xshift=\tmplen,anchor=center] at (P-|O) {\raisebox{3\depth}{\mdf@frametitlefont{ Summary }}};}
\renewrobustcmd\mdf@firstextra{%
    \node[titlebox,xshift=\tmplen,anchor=center] at (P-|O) {\raisebox{3\depth}{\mdf@frametitlefont{ Summary }}};}
```